# Prevent box shadow of element flowing out of its parent div

Tags: html, css

I want the box shadow of a child element only overflow within it's parent element but it goes out of its parent element. How can I fix this?

How it is actually:
[image: image with box shadow overflow out of its parent]

How it is expected to be:
[image: image with box shadow only within it's parent]

```css
#main {
  background: #ddd;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 50px;
}

#child {
  background: #eee;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 50px;
}

#grand-child {
  background: #fff;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 100px 40px red;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="child">
    <div id="grand-child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: overflow:hidden on main ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply add `overflow: hidden`

```css
#main {
  background: #ddd;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#child {
  background: #eee;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#grand-child {
  background: #fff;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 100px 40px red;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="child">
    <div id="grand-child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a CSS property to the `#child` that `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: Stack Overflow works like an encyclopedia: we ask that chatter not be included in answers. A moderator already made an edit to this answer that removed the chatter, but you rolled it back. I'm not sure if that was an accidental misclick of the "rollback" button, but that kind of commentary doesn't belong in an answer here.